# How to invoke a simple webservice with camel?

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, blueprint

this is my route:

```
<route>
<from uri="timer:timerName?period=2000"/>
<to uri="ahc:http://www.google.com/search?q=Camel"/>
<log message="${property.CamelHttpResponseCode}"/>
</route>
```

i want to get response code status but i got this error

```
Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]
```

How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess reading the "Get the response code" paragraph in the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/ahc.html) would have helped :

```
Exchange exchange = template.send("ahc:http://www.google.com/search", new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("hl=en&q=activemq"));
     }
});
Message out = exchange.getOut();
int responseCode = out.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but i want to do it inside the route in the blueprint.xml not with POJO

Comment: the AHC stands for Async Http Client. You can not get the result in your route just after the ahc call. Or you have to disable async.

Answer (score 0):

For this simple case you can use camel-jetty. Otherwise there are additional components such as Camel-Restlet for calling and exposing HTTP services.
http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <to uri="http://www.google.com/search?q=Camel"/>
<route>
```

Edit:

Just for testing purposes you can do like this:

```
<route>
    <from uri="jetty://localhost:5050/test"/>
    <to uri="jetty://http://www.google.com?q=Camel"/>
<route>
```

Then use a tool like postman in chrome or fiddler and call your localhost service.

Comment: i did this but with direct component the route dont start: i cannot read the result i got this message : Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-620133 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.359 seconds nothing else